# Weird pattern on my MacBook Air top surface

Tags: macbook-pro

After unbagging a MacBook Air on the top panel where the Apple logo is some weird patterns​ were generated. I not sure what are those​ .. can someone explain?

The bag just has some black foam material inside.

[image: some pattern]

[image]

I didn't do any photoshopping. I just used a filter to improve the visibility of the pattern in the pics.

Its opacity is too low and if we rub it gets removed.

Comment: This is one of the rare Crop Circle MB Airs. Please add the [Köppen-Geiger climate classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6ppen_climate_classification) of your location!

Comment: That almost looks like the way it does when it still has the plastic wrap on the top cover.

Comment: @klanomath i live in Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India (Aw).

Comment: @WilliamTFroggard hmm can you share some pic of that if you have